# コンソール画面にエラーが表示されてStorage機能が使えない

Tags: firebase

上限に達してしまったのか？
Google Cloud Platformで権限の確認をしましたが問題なかったです。
ログインし直したりもしましたが変わりません。
このプロジェクトのみStorage機能がストップしています。

[image: キャプチャー]

Answer (score 0):

firebaseサポートの方からご連絡頂いたところ、1日あたりのダウンロードできる量を超えていたみたいです。